# When is graph G with n vertices is isomorphic to complement $\bar G$?

Tags: graph-theory

Question : When is graph G with n vertices is isomorphic to complement $\bar G$?

So, total no of edges that a n vertex graph can have is = $n \choose 2$. And if G is isomorphic to $\bar G$ then no of edges in G is equal to no of edges in $\bar G$. So no of edges in G = $\frac{1}{2}$$ n \choose 2$ . But for this to be an integer, n = 4k or n = 4k+1 for some integer k.

My question is : Is this the only requirement? That is, is $n = 4k$ or $4k+1$   the sufficient condition to construct such a graph G?  Does it have anything to do with the fact that G and $\bar G$ can both be bipartite if both of them don't have any triangle in it? The question asks to think about what is the condition of G and $\bar G$ simultaneously bipartite.

Comment: Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. **(1)** If $G$ and $\overline G$ are both bipartite then $n\le4$ (and indeed $P_4$ is a bipartite graph which is isomorphic to its complement). **(2)** If $G$ and $\overline G$ are both triangle-free then $n\le5$; for example, $C_5$ is triangle-free and isomorphic to its complement. **(3)** If $n=4k$ or $n=4k+1,$ then there is an $n$-vertex graph which is isomorphic to its complement. Search this site for self-complementary graph.

Comment: So you mean $C_5$ and its complement are triangle free but they are not bipartite? Please see edit, I changed "iff" to "if". Also I'm confused, so does it mean, because if G and $\bar G$ are isomorphic then their vertex degrees if listed will be equivalent sets, so is only $n(n-1)/4$ no of edges is enough for my answer?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Sorry for bad sentence construction. I am asking, is it sufficient condition(I understand it is necessary condition)for n to be = 4k or 4k+1 to construct a graph G with n vertices which has the self-complementary property? And in that case, no of edges of G is = $n(n-1)/4$

Comment: Yes. Isn't that what I said in point **(3)** of my first comment?

Comment: You said if n=4k or 4k+1, it is true. But ok, I get it for any other n it is anyway not happening, thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n=4k$. Then the following graph $G$ is self-complementary:
Let $V=\{1,2,\ldots, 4k\}$, add edges between $u$ and $v$ if

- both $u,v$ are $\le 2k$ or
- exactly one of $u,v$ is $\le k$ and $|u-v|$ is even.

Then $$\tag1x\mapsto\begin{cases}x+2k&\text{if }x\le 2k\\x-2k+1&\text{if }2k<x<4k\\1&\text{if }x=4k\end{cases}$$
is an isomorphism of $G$ with its complement $\bar G$.

---

Now let $n=4k+1$. Start with the graph $G$ constructed for $n=4k$ and add a new vertex $0$. Add edges from $0$ to $x$ for $1\le x\le 2k$. The map $(2)$ extended by mapping $0\mapsto 0$ is an isomorphism of this new graph $G'$ with its complement $\overline {G'}$.